# ¿Cómo reproduzco música mp3 en java?

Tags: java

tengo u problema con mi código para reproducir archivos mp.3. Lo que sucede es que solo puede acceder a la música desde la carpeta de mi pc, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de reproducir música mp.3 con los archivos que tengo en mi proyecto y no desde la dirección de la carpeta de mi pc.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
    Player rep = new Player(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Nico\\Downloads\\pokemon.mp3"));
            rep.play();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez algo como esto:

```
    AudioInputStream audioIn;
    try {
        audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/audio/hola.mp3"));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioIn);
        clip.start();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: me da un error en AudioPlayer dice que lo debe cambiar por AdvancedPlayer sabes por que sucede eso?